# Function starts from the middle

Tags: c++, client, sip

I am trying to parse the SIP REQUEST messages. When I call the function to parse the message, it starts from the middle with no reason.

Input is:

```
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1448207213;received=127.0.0.1;rport=52447
From: <sip:croolman@127.0.0.1>;tag=glitchy1448207213
To: <sip:croolman@127.0.0.1>;tag=as4589087f
Call-ID: croolman1448207213
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="3adf9b5b"
Content-Length: 0
```

Function for parse:

```
void generateOutput(string input, int response){
  string help = "";
  cout << "***********EXAMPLE - INPUT *************" << endl;
  cout << input << endl;
  int i = 0;      
  cout << to_string(global_iterator) << " "; // prints the number at the start of the output
  global_iterator++;
  size_t pozic;
  if(response == 1){
    while(input[i] != ' '){ // get to 401
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    while(input[i] != ' '){ // print 401
        cout << input[i];
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    cout << " ";
    while(input[i] != '\n'){ // print Unauthorized
        cout << input[i];
        i++;
    }
    pozic = input.find("From:"); // find From:
    pozic += 5;                   // get to position where adress starts
    while(input[pozic] != ':'){
        pozic++;
    }
    pozic++;
    while(input[pozic] != '>'){
       cout << input[pozic];
       pozic++;
    }
    cout << " ";
    pozic = input.find("To:");
    pozic += 3;
    while(input[pozic] != ':'){
        pozic++;
    }
    pozic++;
    while(input[pozic] != '>'){
        cout << input[pozic];
        pozic++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }else{
    while(input[i] != ' '){
       cout << input[i]; 
       i++;
    }
    cout << " ";
    pozic = input.find("From:");
    pozic += 5;
    while(input[pozic] != ':'){
        pozic++;
    }
    pozic++;
    while(input[pozic] != '>'){
       cout << input[pozic];
       pozic++;
    }
    cout << " ";
    pozic = input.find("To:");
    pozic += 3;
    while(input[pozic] != ':'){
        pozic++;
    }
    pozic++;
    while(input[pozic] != '>'){
        cout << input[pozic];
        pozic++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
```

Global iterator is global variable counting the messages.
The expected output is :

```
1 401 Unauthorized croolman@127.0.0.1 croolman@127.0.0.1
```

The result I get:

```
1 REGISTER croolman@127.0.0.1 croolman@127.0.0.1
***********EXAMPLE - INPUT *************
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1448215167;received=127.0.0.1;rport=53191
From: <sip:croolman@127.0.0.1>;tag=glitchy1448215167
To: <sip:croolman@127.0.0.1>;tag=as017834f4
Call-ID: croolman1448215167
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="28af07e9"
Content-Length: 0


croolman@127.0.0.1 croolman@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This does not look like C to me, it rather seems like C++

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist you're right, my fault

Comment: Are you sure that your 'input' parameter does actually contain that data that you posted?  I just ran your code, and it does print the "401" and the "unauthorized" (albeit without spaces in between).

Comment: yeah, i get the same result as @BenRubin but the weird thing is he can get the `Form:` one correctly. I suggest you try to print full input in your code...

Comment: @BenRubin I don't undestand. I have checked the input. It is the expected one, but output is still wrong.

Comment: @Croolman Put a `cout << input` at the top of your method and make sure that the input is as you except.  Once you do that, it'll help us find the issue if you post the entire output of your function, including the `cout << input`  Also, are you sure that you're running the exact code that you posted?  There are other peculiarities, such as the `cout << to_string(global_iterator) << " "` not printing in your example output.

Comment: @BenRubin I have added more code - else part of the if prints out the first row for given input REGISTER message - that one is right, but when it has to go the main if part, it doesnt work as intended, as you can see in the output

Comment: I'm still getting different output from you http://imgur.com/6wRh7Bw.  Try changing `while(input[i] != '\n')` to `while(input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\r' && input[i] != '\r\n')` and see what happens.  If that doesn't work, please upload a screenshot of your output.

Comment: That is the solution! Linux doesn't allow me to compare `'\r\n'`, but adding just another `'\r'` to compare works for me.